# Calculating the first order partial derivatives of the Gaussian function

Tags: proof-verification, partial-derivative

I am trying to calculate the first order partial derivatives of the Gaussian function. My calculations look correct to me but when I implement them in a C program I do not get the desired result. So, I am trying to figure out if my maths are wrong or if my code is wrong.

Assume we have the following Gaussian function:

$$f(x)=ae^{-\tfrac{(x-b)^2}{2c^2}}+d$$

The first order partial derivatives of the Gaussian function with respect to each parameter according to my calculations are:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}&=e^{-\tfrac{(x-b)^2}{2c^2}}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial b}&=ae^{-\tfrac{(x-b)^2}{2c^2}}\frac{x-b}{c^2}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial c}&=ae^{-\tfrac{(x-b)^2}{2c^2}}\frac{(x-b)^2}{c^3}\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial d}&=1
\end{align}

Can someone verify that my maths are correct? Thank you.

Comment: @5xum, you are right, they are correct.

Comment: Yes, your derivatives are all correct. What do you mean when you speak about problems in a C program ?

Comment: Thank you all for your help guys. @ClaudeLeibovici : I am using a minimization library (cMPFit) in which you can optionally provide the derivatives of the function. If my maths are correct I guess that I am not supplying the Jacobian matrix to the mpfit correctly.

Comment: @AstrOne. This is probably the case : good derivatives but wrong Jacobian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For inspections such as these, wolfram alpha is very useful. For example:
[This link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d/da%20a%2aexp%28-%28x-b%29%5E2/%282c%5E2%29%29%20%2b%20d) shows that your first derivative is OK. Similarly for the others:

[Derivative over $b$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d/db%20a%2aexp%28-%28x-b%29%5E2/%282c%5E2%29%29%20%2b%20d)

[Derivative over $c$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d/dc%20a%2aexp%28-%28x-b%29%5E2/%282c%5E2%29%29%20%2b%20d)

[Derivative over $d$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive%20a%2aexp%28-%28x-b%29%5E2/%282c%5E2%29%29%20%2b%20d%20wrt%20d)

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know you can do this with wolfram alpha! Thank you my friend!

Comment: Happy to help. Basically, any "gruntwork" you do can be done in alpha, you just have to know how to ask...:)